# matdatepicker holding the date even after refreshing page

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am using matdatepicker for angular2. It's holding the value of dates even after I am refreshing the page. How can I reset these placeholders after the page is refreshed or I click on submit button?
Code is as below:

HTML :

```
<div class="div1">
   <form (ngSubmit)="getJobsByDateRange(f)" #f="ngForm" >
     <label style="float:left;padding:7px;"> From : </label>
      <mat-form-field style="float:left;padding:7px;">
        <input type="date" matInput [matDatepicker]="picker1" placeholder="Choose a date" name="fromDate" 
        [(ngModel)]="eventobj.fromDate" #eventDate="ngModel"  required>
        <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker1"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
        <mat-datepicker #picker1></mat-datepicker>
      </mat-form-field>
      <label style="float:left;padding:7px;"> To : </label>
      <mat-form-field style="float:left;padding:7px;">
        <input type="date" matInput [matDatepicker]="picker2" placeholder="Choose a date" name="toDate" 
        [(ngModel)]="eventobj.toDate" #eventDate="ngModel"  required>
        <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker2"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
        <mat-datepicker #picker2></mat-datepicker>
      </mat-form-field>
      <button mat-raised-button class="btn btn-info btn-sm"> Submit </button>
      </form>
</div>
```

TS :

```
eventobj = {
  fromDate: new Date(this.defaultDate - 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7), // One week
  toDate: new Date(this.defaultDate),
}
getJobsByDateRange() {
  let fromDate1 = this.eventobj.fromDate;
  let toDate1 = this.eventobj.toDate;
  let fromDate2=null;
  let toDate2=null;
  if(fromDate1!=null && toDate1!=null){
    fromDate2= ("00"+fromDate1.getDate()).slice(-2)+"-"+("0"+(1+fromDate1.getMonth())).slice(-2)+"-"+fromDate1.getFullYear()
    toDate2= ("00"+toDate1.getDate()).slice(-2)+"-"+("0"+(1+toDate1.getMonth())).slice(-2)+"-"+toDate1.getFullYear()

  }
  else{
    alert("Enter a valid date!")
  }
  alert(fromDate2+"||"+toDate2)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution that worked out for me.

Modification for TS file:

```
getJobsByDateRange(form) {
// rest of code
form.resetForm();
}
```